# Error in OData GET returns 406/404 with multiple parameters in different cases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, get, odata

I have been trying executing a get method with multiple parameters but sometime result is 404 or else if it finds the method then 406(Not Acceptable). It is working with single params.

**CASE 1**: Single Params -> Working returns string

Request url -

```js
http://localhost/odata/Monitoring/GetTestingDone(number=1234)
```

Method -

```html
        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTestingDone(long number)
        {
          string a = Convert.ToString(number);
          return Ok(a);
        }
```

Registered in edmx model -

```html
builder.EntityType<TestingType>().Collection.Function("GetTestingDone").Returns<string>().Parameter<long>("number");
```

**CASE 2**: Multiple params - returns 404 Not Found

Request URL -

```html
http://localhost/odata/MonitoringAttributes/IsTested(number1=,number2=,number3=13675,value=FederalRegistration)
```

Method -

```html
[EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult IsTested(int? number1, int? number2, int? number3, string value)
        {
            
                ObjectParameter isTested = new ObjectParameter("isTested", typeof(bool));

                var result = db.vm_getTested(number1, number2, number3, value, isTested)
                    .ToList();
                bool asd = Convert.ToBoolean(isTested.Value);
                
                return Ok(asd);

            }
```

Registered in edmx model -

```html
var IsTested = builder.EntityType<TestingType>()
                .Collection
                .Function("IsTested")
                .Returns<bool>();

            IsTested.Parameter<int?>("number1");
            IsTested.Parameter<int?>("number2");
            IsTested.Parameter<int?>("number3");
            IsTested.Parameter<string>("value");
```

**CASE 3** : Enters method but returns 406(Not Acceptable)

Requested URL -

```html
http://localhost/odata/MonitoringAttributes/IsTested?number1=&number2=&number3=13675&value=FederalRegistration
```

Method -

```html
[HttpGet]
[Route("odata/Monitoring/IsTested")]
EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult IsTested(int? number1, int? number2, int? number3, string value)
        {
            
                ObjectParameter isTested = new ObjectParameter("isTested", typeof(bool));

                var result = db.vm_getTested(number1, number2, number3, value, isTested)
                    .ToList();
                bool asd = Convert.ToBoolean(isTested.Value);
                
                return Ok(asd);

            }
```

Registered in edmx model is same as **CASE 2**.

So am I missing something or doing it incorrectly. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research and found the way to do it -

Request url -

```html
http://localhost/odata/MonitoringAttributes/Class.IsTested(number1=null,number2=null,number3=13675,value='FederalRegistration')
```

So here no blank values are accepted we need to pass string "null" and the string will be in single quotes and not double quotes.

Method ->

```html
[HttpGet]
EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult IsTested([FromOdataUrl]int? number1,[FromOdataUrl] int? number2,[FromOdataUrl] int? number3, string value)
        {
            
                ObjectParameter isTested = new ObjectParameter("isTested", typeof(bool));

                var result = db.vm_getTested(number1, number2, number3, value, isTested)
                    .ToList();
                bool asd = Convert.ToBoolean(isTested.Value);
                
                return Ok(asd);

            }
```

Here the param are prefixed with "[FromOdataUrl]" only for int or long. For string or bool its not required.

Registered in edmx model is same as **CASE2**